# Resize UIImage before uploading to Firebase storage in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimage, storage

I have set up my application so that when I press the button "cambiaimmagineutente" a picker controller appears and I can choose the image which I then upload to FIRStorage using the "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL". I cannot find a way to resize the image before uploading it to save space and to place it in a smaller image view.
Here is the code:

```
 @IBAction func cambiaImmagineUtente(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)


    // if it's a photo from the library, not an image from the camera
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *), let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [referenceUrl], options: nil)
        let asset = assets.firstObject
        asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
            let imageFile = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL
            let filePath = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid +
            "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000))/\(imageFile!.lastPathComponent)"
            // [START uploadimage]
            self.storageRef.child(filePath)
                .putFile(imageFile!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        //an error occured
                        print("Error uploading: \(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    self.uploadSuccess(metadata!, storagePath: filePath)
            }
            // [END uploadimage]
        })
    } else {
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else { return }
        let imagePath = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid +
        "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg"
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        self.storageRef.child(imagePath)
            .put(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    //an error occured
                    print("Error uploading: \(error)")

                    return
                }
                self.uploadSuccess(metadata!, storagePath: imagePath)
        }
    }
}

func uploadSuccess(_ metadata: FIRStorageMetadata, storagePath: String) {
    print("Upload Succeeded!")
    //self.urlTextView.text = metadata.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
    UserDefaults.standard.set(storagePath, forKey: "storagePath")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    //self.downloadPicButton.isEnabled = true
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = image.size

        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

        var newSize: CGSize
        if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
```

Use:

```
let resizedImage = resizeImage(image: selectedImage, targetSize: CGSize.init(width: 300, height: 300))
```

make sure you also make a write rule to a max value in your storage rules!

Comment: But how do I then post this image to firebase? Because it returns a newImage which is not a URL... or I need to keep the same function as before and this only changes the seize of the output image from the picker controller?

Comment: You have a line ".putFile(imageFile!", replace that with ".putFile(resizedImage".

Comment: When using "let resizedImage = resizeImage(image: selectedImage, targetSize: CGSize.init(width: 300, height: 300))", it gives me use of unresolved identifier resizedImage. Also I did not understand where I have to insert i.